# Highlight/select multiple divs with ranges w/ contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, range

Let's say I have a set of `contenteditable="true"` divs.

```
<div id="0" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="1" contenteditable..></div>
<div...etc></div>
```

**I can't have one div, multiple divs is a must.** How could I highlight the content of more than one div? Using ranges? Anything else?

Comment: @JC0C611: Numbers are not valid values for `id`s according to the W3C

Comment: That is pretty weird, but lets say they where "_0", "_1"...etc, that would be valid, right?

Comment: @JC0C611: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".") (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

Comment: I don't see why lol but I might fix that later

Comment: @JC0C611: Why? Because that's how the tokens are defined in the specification. For the most part you can get away with IDs that start with numbers but certain things may not work correctly (like styling the element by using an ID selector).

Comment: @ZackTheHuman Actually, according to HTML5 the only restriction on an element's ID is that it may not have whitespace: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @rvighne Yes, that's true for HTML5. It wasn't true for previous versions of the specifications (like the one linked in a previous comment). I suppose HTML5 is so prevalent that it not longer matters, but there are issues with old browsers like IE7 when using names and IDs that don't conform to the pre-HTML5 rules. If you have to support those browsers then you don't really have a choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on the browser. See [this example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/timdown/2j8vk/2/) for a test of two methods using Ranges. The first attempts to create a Range per editable `<div>` and add all of them to the selection. The second attempts to create a single Range encompassing the contents of two editable `<div>`s.

Results:

- In all browsers, it is impossible for the user to create a selection that lives in more than one editable element;
- Firefox is the most permissive of the major browsers. Both programmatic methods work.
- Safari and Chrome is the least permissive: neither method selects content from more than one editable element.
- Opera 11 does not support multiple Ranges in the selection, but does support a selected Range spanning more than one editable element.
- IE pre-version 9 does not support DOM Range or the same `Selection` API as other browsers, but the equivalent `TextRange` code does not allow selection from more than one editable element.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wonder if it could be possible to mimic the ranges using background divs and javascript..

Comment: I'll go ahead and select this as the accepted answer, and create another question on how to mimic ranges w/ divs and JS.

Comment: @JCOC611: It's not so much the Range you'll be mimicking as the selection. Creating as many Ranges as you like works fine, it's selecting them that's the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to switch the divs to `contenteditable="false"` on the fly as a consequence of starting a selection in one of them. Something like this gives you the idea (using JQuery):

```
$('div').bind("selectstart", function() {
    $('div').attr("contenteditable", false);
});​
```

[Here's a fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/T7b3r/32/) (only tested in Chrome).

Note in the fiddle example that the first ContentEditable Div gets the focus. This allows you to type away as normal, but as soon as you select anything, using mouse or keyboard, you'll see you can extend the selection across divs as usual.

This obviously needs fleshing out to work with multiple browsers and to turn back to `contenteditable="true"` appropriately. But I think the approach is valid.

Comment: add to this an onclick -> contenteditable = true and you're halfway there (this is where I am atm)

Comment: It helped me..have a question..I do as @Prozi said but it doesn't show cursor at that position I can add but cursor is not there? any solution? demo : http://jsfiddle.net/T7b3r/55/

Comment: This was a neat little trick, far more simple than building a complicated selection.

Comment: I got this to work by setting 'contenteditable'=true on 'mouseup'.  I also needed to implemented a function to focus on the current element if there was no selection.  I picked up the "data-div-id" from the selected div on 'mouseup' and focused that element.  Note that it was necessary to first reactivate 'contenteditable'=true, otherwise it is not possible to focus on that element.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to turn on the `contentaditable` of the parent element instead of turning it off on each child.

```js
const editableDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("editable")
let selecting = false

for (const editableDiv of editableDivs) {
  editableDiv.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
    if (selecting)
      document.body.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")
  })
}

document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
  selecting = true
})

document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
  document.body.setAttribute("contenteditable", "false")
  selecting = false
})
```

```html
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
  This is the first editable div.
</div>

<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
  This is the second editable div.
</div>
```