# How to mimic JS ranges/selections with divs as backgrounds?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, range

I need to mimic ranges/selections (those that highlight content on a website, and when you press for ex `CTRL + C` you copy the content) with divs as backgrounds. Chances are that the "highlighting divs" will be `position:absolute;`

```
<div id="highlight">
   <!-- The highlightor divs would go here -->
</div>
<div id="edit">
   <!-- The divs to be highlighted (that have text) would go here -->
</div>
```

Edit: Functionalities such as copying are essential.

PS: If you're curious about "why", refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777860/highlight-select-multiple-divs-with-ranges-w-contenteditable).
I created a new question because I felt the old one was pretty much answered, and this one differed to much from that one.

Comment: Where did you go JCOC611, and what did you find there?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the concept, with some code to get you started.  Every time text is selected in the page, append that text to a hidden textarea on the page and then select the textarea.  Then, wrap the original selection in a span to make it look selected.  This way, you have the appearance of a selection, and since the hidden textarea is actually selected, when the user hits "ctrl+c" they are copying the text from the textarea.

To get the full functionality you are looking for, you'll probably want to extend this.  Sniff keys for "ctrl+a" (for select all).  I don't think you'll be able to override right-click behavior... at least not easily or elegantly.  But this much is at least a proof of concept for you to run with.

```
window.onload = init;
function init()
{
    document.getElementById("hidden").value = "";
    document.body.ondblclick = interceptSelection;
    document.body.onmouseup = interceptSelection;
}
function interceptSelection(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden");
    if (target == hidden) return;
    var range, text;
    if (window.getSelection)
    {
        var sel = getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount == 0) return;
        range = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    }
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange)
    {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
    }
    text = "text" in range ? range.text : range.toString();
    if (text)
    {
        if (range.surroundContents)
        {
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.className = "selection";
            range.surroundContents(span);
        }
        else if (range.pasteHTML)
        {
            range.pasteHTML("<span class=\"selection\">" + text + "</span>")
        }
        hidden.value += text;
    }
    hidden.select();
}
```

Here's the css I used in my test to hide the textarea and style the selected text:

```
#hidden
{
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
}
.selection
{
    background-color: Highlight;
    color: HighlightText;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't rely on the current document selection because I can't select two or more divs at a time (and I need to, check the "why" question linked).

Comment: From your question and the linked question, it sounds like you have two requirements.  1. Allow the user to "select" multiple pieces of text.  Ie, the text will be highlighted as it usually is when text is selected.  2. Allow the user to copy that text by hitting ctrl+c.  Have I got the requirements right?  I've posted my above code at my website so you can see a live demo: http://jumpingfishes.com/multiselect.htm

Comment: There is, however, a third requirement: There are several divs that can be edited (`<div contenteditable="true"></div>`), the user must be able to select more than one of them, as the linked question suggests.